# Mysql select auto skip first value

Tags: php, mysql

i have mysql table looks like this one

```
id  title       start            resourceId
```

---

```
5   event1  2014-08-15 08:00:00     STK1    
6   event2  2014-08-15 08:00:00     STK2    
7   event3  2014-08-15 08:00:00     STK3
```

And php query:

```
<?php 
include("config.php");

$data = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `evenement`");
$zaznam = mysql_fetch_array ($data);
while($zaznam = mysql_fetch_array ($data))
{
   $arr2[] = $zaznam["start"].$zaznam["resourceId"];
}

print_r($arr2);
?>
```

This query works almost fine, but i always get only event2 and 3. It absolutely won't see first result at all.

Here is my **print_r($arr2);**

```
Array ( [0] => 2014-08-15 08:00:00STK2 [1] => 2014-08-15 08:00:00STK3 )
```

I dont understand why i get only two results. It work all time, but today, I emptied my table and it stop work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two calls of mysql_fetch_array(), the first one before the loop gets the first row.

Use

```
$data = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `evenement`");
while($zaznam = mysql_fetch_array ($data))
      {
       $arr2[] = $zaznam["start"].$zaznam["resourceId"];
      }
```

instead.

Comment: Easy and simple answer! It works dude, thank you for fast answer. I mark ti as solution in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching your resoults twice:

```
 $zaznam = mysql_fetch_array ($data);
        while($zaznam = mysql_fetch_array ($data))
```

remove the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `mysql_fetch_array` twice, remove this line:

```
$zaznam = mysql_fetch_array ($data);
```

You are never using it anyway since you overwrite the value in the while loop.

Also note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code before the while loop.

```
$zaznam = mysql_fetch_array ($data);
```

You get error because when call to mysql_fetch_array function it get the results from the mysql_query results.